# IIS and WPF video streaming

Tags: wpf, iis, streaming

I need someone to point to right direction in both silverlight in WPF video streaming.

I have two projects, one is a Silverlight web page and the other is a WPF project. The goal is, on the WPF application the user is able to upload a video to the server, and the Silverlight web page streams it using a any web protocol (most likely http).

I'm using Expression Encoder SDK to build the code that re-encodes the video files (since the original video files will be very big, over 1gb each), and so far I think I've got it right, but now I need to stream it on the web, and I'm not being able to do so.

The silverlight web page is hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.0.

I've been reading about IIS streaming, but everything I find points that every time the user wants to add a video, it must go to IIS interface and add it manually, and that cannot be the only way, since the user knows nothing about IIS.

If possible I would like some code examples on how to achieve streaming through IIS, and some pointer on what I could do, or am doing wrong...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why user have to manually do it everytime in IIS. From your WPF app, make it store your video in a specific location inside your IIS. Also do a one time configuration in your IIS to deliver the video extension you are uploading, if its mp4 or wmv, give it the MIME type, "application/octet-stream", so when a user requests it, it will be delivered by IIS.

No, configure your silverlight app to read the file from your IIS directory (you must be knowing the filename it got saved in IIS in the first place.)

If you need to have a "streaming" experience, IIS won't be enough, you will have to use a streaming server like windows media server or flash media server.

Hope this helps.